# How can I use settings from another form in project to populate file directory to list exe files

Tags: vb.net

Apologies in advance this is my first project.

I am creating a VB project and have created a settings(FormSettings.vb) page where the user browses to their steam library and that inputs into a text box(Textbox1.Text) and got it to save etc. On myy main form of the project I have a drop down box that I want to populate all the exe files which works ok when i specify the directory in the code but what I want it to do it pull the directory path from the users setting

Working

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim directory = "D:\Steam Library"
    Dim files() As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim dirinfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
    files = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.exe", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each file In files
        cmbSelectGame.Items.Add(file)
    Next

End Sub'''
```

I have also tried

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim directory = FormSettings.Textbox1.Text
    Dim files() As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim dirinfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
    files = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.exe", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each file In files
        cmbSelectGame.Items.Add(file)
    Next

End Sub
```

Any guidance is appreciated and thank you in advance

Comment: There is a proper settings system in .NET; I recommend you use that

Comment: You've not really explained exactly what isn't working for you but I'm going to take a guess.  1)  In Form1_Load Dim directory = FormSettings.... is refereing to the FormSettings Type instead of an instance of FormSettings.  2) Access modifiers on the FormSettings Controls hides it from Form1.